# Get info from dynamic/growing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a form to create a contract, where that contract can have one or more users associated.

The area to input the users info, starts with only one field of one user, and one button to add more fields if needed.

```
<div id="utilizadores" class="row">
            <div id="utilizador1" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeUtilizador1" placeholder="Nome Utilizador">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="funcaoUtilizador1" placeholder="Função">
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the starting div

Clicking on Add User button it adds a new div under the "utilizador1"

```
<div id="utilizadores" class="row">
<div id="utilizador1" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeUtilizador1" placeholder="Nome Utilizador">
        </div>                       
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="funcaoUtilizador1" placeholder="Função">
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
<div id="utilizador2" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeUtilizador2" placeholder="Nome Utilizador">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="funcaoUtilizador2" placeholder="Função">
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

My question is, how can I get the number of users created, and insert them into a list using Javascript. The list will be a attribute of a Object (Contract).

What i have til now:

```
function test_saveItem() {           
var contract = new Object();
contract.Dono = <% =uID %>;

contract.BoostMes = $("#boostMes").val();
contract.BoostAno = $("#boostAno").val();

var ListaUtilizadores = [];

var divs = document.getElementsByName("utilizador");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    var user = new Object();
    user.Nome = $('#nomeUtilizador' + i).val();
    ListaUtilizadores.push(user);
}

 var test = JSON.stringify({ "contract": contract });
}
```

Any help appreciated

Edit: Got to a solution thanks to Shilly

```
List = [];
        Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.user')).forEach(function (node, index) {
            List.push({              
                "name" : document.getElementById('nameUser' + (index + 1)).value,
                "job" : document.getElementById('jobUser' + (index + 1)).value
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? But adding it into the addUser function as Super Hirnet says, will be more performant.

```
var divs =  document.querySelector('#utilizadores').childNodes,
    users = [];
Array.slice.call(divs).forEach(function (node, index) {
    users.push({
        "name" : divs[index].getElementById('nomeUtilizador' + (index + 1)).value
    });
});
```

Comment: After trying a solution similar to your example, I'm getting a error saying that "node.querySelector is not a function".

The divs array gets populated correctly, reaching the node the code breaks. But thanks for the advance, got me started on the path for a solution.

Comment: Editted. I hope this form will not break the nodes now.

Comment: Didn't work mainly cuz getElementById only works with document.

But got to a solution, edited on main.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have an empty array and on every click of `addUser` put a new object into the array. The object can have information related to the added user.

Comment: This seems to me a good solution, one question tho, I just create a empty user object when clicking addUser? 
The information related to the user will be added how? Or where will that code be? On the Save Contract button?